# Not able to use temp tables from SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have two tasks in control flow. The first task is in sequence container and creates multiple global temp tables. The second task uses these temp tables. Both the tasks are in 'Execute SQL Task'. They both use Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 11.0 driver to connect to SQL Server. I have both the properties set to true. Delay Validation and Retain Same Connection.

When the first Sequence container runs, I see temp tables getting created through management studio window when they are in 'yellow' or running state. As soon as the first task completes, they do become green(completes), the next task is not able to use these global temp tables. Neither can I see these tables in management studio anymore.

How do I retain these temp tables so that they can be used in same dtsx task in subsequent tasks

I have explained that above

Comment: The retain same connection is how I have done it in the past.  One other way is to create a staging table (permeant table that you can use as a temp table) and either just truncate it before each use, or you can drop it after done and recreate it each time.

Comment: Yes, might have to use physical tables if temp tables do not work

Answer (score 2):

As Brad indicates as well as your write up, it seems you're doing everything correct.

Let's try a basic reproduction and let me know whether this does or does not work in your environment. We'll have a two task package, both Execute SQL Tasks

[image]

Create an OLEDB Connection manager with `RetainSameConnection` set to `True`

[image]

## SQL Create global temp

The first execute sql task will create the global temporary table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##SO_77411558;
CREATE TABLE ##SO_77411558
(
   Col1 int
);
```

## SQL Use global temp

In our second Execute SQL Task, we'll add a row to the table

```
INSERT INTO ##SO_77411558
SELECT 3;
```

At this point, I have greens across the board.

If I add an empty Sequence Container after the second Execute SQL Task and put a breakpoint on it

[image]

I can then verify the global tables remain as the package has not completed

```
sqlcmd -S .\dev2017 -E -d tempdb -Q "SELECT T.name FROM sys.tables AS T WHERE T.name like '%SO%'"
name
-----------------
##SO_77411558

(1 rows affected)
```

Comment: Yes, it is working using your approach. I wonder why mine is not working. My temp tables are importing huge data. I do not know if that could be the reason

Comment: I'm happy to work with you to try and reproduce the issue. Perhaps step 1 is to distill your current package down to a single temp table instead of many (the multi-line comment `/* */` is excellent in this regard. Screenshots of your actual package, the connection manager's properties, etc might also help us pin down where it's going awry